# how to install php v8.1.8 on vscode

Tags: php, laravel

i am using laragon php version is 8.1.8 but in vscode it is 7.4.19.
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eXFz.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgaPQ.png)
How do I install php 8.1.8 on vscode?

How do I install php 8.1.8 on vscode?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to update your Windows Environment Variables.

1. Start > search for Environment Variables
2. Once open, find "Path" under the "System variables".
3. In the list, find any existing PHP directory path, delete it.
4. Add your new PHP 8.1.8 path. Should be something like `C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.8-Win32-vs16-x64`
5. Save, restart VSCode

Answer (score 1):

1. In console `php -r "echo PHP_BINARY;"`
2. Change `php.validate.executablePath` in `settings.json` in VsCode To change the PHP settings, open your User or Workspace Settings (Ctrl+,) and type 'php' to filter the list of available settings. Read [more](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php)